# Joomla main menu customization

Tags: joomla

How can I customize the joomla main menu like this:
http://www.ruckuswireless.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to be a quick and easy hack, but you might be able to pull it off with an HTML override. If you want something close, you can probably get close with one of the mega menu extensions.

If you want to hack it yourself, you will need to get a copy of JOOMLAINSTALL/modules/mod_mainmenu/tmpl/default.php and put it in JOOMLAINSTALL/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/mod_mainmenu/default.php once you have made the modifications.

You can use the menu item image for the image at the top of the dropdown. The menu description is a little trickier, but most menu systems use the menu Title for this purpose. When you put in the title you will need a separator so you can then split the title in to the the title and the description. The format would have to be something like MENU TITLE|MENU DESCRIPTION.

This is a pretty big modification but that is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks buddy...this will help me a lot.